# Change adb device name

Tags: adb, build.prop

The Android device identifies itself as "device" for ADB (Android Debug Bridge).

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
5727aa6d        device
```

In my case of the LineageOS 20.0 test build, the name contains whitespaces and therefore cannot be addressed from [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/3545).

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
CDC ACM Data    device
```

Which property can we set to change the `adb device` name?

Comment: [background](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-unofficial-13-lineageos-20-0-64-bit-for-galaxy-tab-a-10-5-2018-wifi-sm-t590.4427597/post-88167961)

Comment: AFAIR adb uses the device serial number so I would expect it to use getprop `ro.boot.serialno` or `ro.serialno`

Comment: nope.. tried on redmi 6 with magisk resetprop from service.d